# How do I link to a DLL from javascript in XULRunner?

Tags: dll, xpcom, xulrunner

I have a dll (that I didn't write) and I would like to use it in an XULRunner application. I know nearly nothing about this, so bear with me. Apparently I can use XPCOM to load the dll and then call functions in it. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could wait until xulrunner includes [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/ctypes.jsm) and call the DLL directly.